# How to get email messages not older than X seconds?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

I use this code to search through my Gmail inbox:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", 993, EMAIL, PASSWORD);
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(new AndTerm(new SearchTerm[] { new SubjectTerm(subject), new FromTerm(new InternetAddress(sender)), new YoungerTerm((int)TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(3)) }));
```

But I get this error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: A4 BAD Could not parse command;
```

If I remove the `YoungerTerm` search term, the search call succeeds and returns messages, but I need to reduce the results by adding the `YoungerTerm` filter.

Comment: The IMAP protocol does not support search for such fine grained measurements of time.  It only allows searching on day boundaries.

Comment: Related: [use of YoungerTerm/OlderTerm on server without WITHIN support fails](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8550) which is fixed in JavaMail 1.6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [YoungerTerm](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/YoungerTerm.html) class depends on an IMAP extension gmail does not support, [RFC 5032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5032). The only way to do what you want is to retrieve the `INTERNALDATE` and filter in the client.

A bit strange that javamail will let you create and send a command that uses YoungerTerm; surely it ought to know that the server will reject it?

Comment: The class that converts the Java SearchTerms into an IMAP SEARCH string doesn't have access to the IMAPProtocol object that knows what capabilities the server supports.  That could be fixed, of course (it's only software), but that's why it doesn't detect this problem earlier and instead relies on the server failing the command.

Comment: Does anyone know which IMAP search filters does Gmail support ?

Comment: Gmail supports the ones in [RFC 3501 section 6.4.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4).

Comment: Gmail also supports [ESEARCH, RFC 4731](https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4731#section-3.1)

Comment: No, it does not add any terms specifically, but does allow customizing the SEARCH results.